# Populate List<enum> based on constants?

Tags: c#

I have a `FaultType` `enum` with more than 100 members.

```
public enum FaultType
{
    FaultType1,
    FaultType2,
    FaultType3,
    FaultType4,
    FaultType5,
}
```

And I have a `FaultTypeConstants` `class` corresponding to `FaultType`.

```
public class FaultTypeConstants
{
    public const int FaultType1 = 600;
    public const int FaultType2 = 100;
    public const int FaultType3 = 453;
    public const int FaultType4 = 200;
    public const int FaultType5 = 300;
}
```

I tried..

```
    public static List<FaultType> GetFaults(List<int> FaultConstants)
    {
        var faults = new List<FaultType>();
        FaultConstants.ForEach(fc => {
            switch (fc)
            {
                case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType1:
                    faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType1);
                    break;
                case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType2:
                    faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType2);
                    break;
                case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType3:
                    faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType3);
                    break;
                case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType4:
                    faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType4);
                    break;
                case FaultTypeConstants.FaultType5:
                    faults.Add(FaultType.FaultType5);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

        return faults;
    }
```

Now, how can i populate the `List<FaultType>` based on `FaultTypeConstants` values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just provide the constant as part of the enum itself:

```
public enum FaultType
{
    FaultType1 = 600,
    FaultType2 = 100,
    FaultType3 = 453,
    FaultType4 = 200,
    FaultType5 = 300,
}
```

Then you can just cast:

```
FaultType ft = (FaultType) 600;
```

For the list, you can iterate in a `foreach` loop, or if you like LINQ you can can just use:

```
List<FaultType> listOfFaultTypes = listOfInts.Cast<FaultType>().ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments that you can't change the enum at all, I suggest you build a dictionary that you can use for lookup.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, FaultType> FaultTypeDictionary =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(FaultType))
        .Cast<FaultType>()
        .ToDictionary(
            x => (int)typeof(FaultTypeConstants).GetField(x.ToString()).GetValue(null),
            x => x);

public static List<FaultType> GetFaults(List<int> faults)
{
    return faults.Select(x => FaultTypeDictionary[x]).ToList();
}
```

It uses reflection, but only makes one pass against the enum.  Since it is static, you will not have the cost of doing this for each lookup.

Comment: Agreed. But that is not my requirement. See my answer below.

Comment: What part of this won't meet your requirements?  Are you not allowed to change the enum?

Comment: Yes. I will not allowed the assign the value for FaultType. That is the reason i maintained separate class for that. Though it is bad design but it is my project requirement.

Comment: My solution which is below is working fine. Is the better code ?

Comment: @Prasad, Instead of maintaining const in separate class, cant you maintain dictionary of int,faulttype. This way, you can just lookup on dictionary instead of going Reflection way

Comment: @Tilak, Agreed. This is good solution. But MattJohnson has a solution for this which exactly suite for me.

Comment: @Tilak - Funny, that is exactly what I was working on while you were commenting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx)

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(FaultType)).Cast<FaultType>().ToList()
```

**EDIT**

Based on function signature in the OP, there is a eleaner way

```
public static List<FaultType> GetFaults(List<int> FaultConstants)
{
   return FaultConstants.Cast<FaultType>().ToList()
}
```

Comment: First will get all FaultType in list, but based on question inferred better, i updated my answer. See the edited part.

Comment: This won't work unless the enum value matches, and then you are basically doing the same thing that I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution.

```
public static List<FaultType> GetFaults(List<int> FaultConstants)
{
    return typeof(FaultTypeConstants)
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(fi => FaultConstants.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(fi.GetValue(null))))
        .Select(fi => (FaultType)Enum.Parse(typeof(FaultType), fi.Name)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Reflection on a large list is going to be very slow.  There is a better way.  I will have an updated answer shortly...